# run QApplication in android studio ,native c++ , cmake

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I try to use qt in android studio with cmake ,the starting point is create a native c++ project in androind studio ,then I revise the CMakeLits.txt like this ：

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project("cpp_trial")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/home/yskj/Qt/5.15.2/android")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC YES)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

add_library( cpp_trial SHARED native-lib.cpp window.cpp)


find_library(log-lib log)


target_link_libraries( cpp_trial  ${log-lib} Qt::Widgets  Qt::Core  Qt::Gui)
```

The exported JNI function is like this :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <QApplication>
#include "window.h"


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_cpp_1trial_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject ) {
 int argc =1;
 char* argv[]={"dummy"};
 QApplication app(argc,argv);
 Dialog diag;
 diag.showMaximized();
 return app.exec();
}
```

and the  mainActivity java class is like this

```
package com.example.cpp_trial
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.cpp_trial.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
       // binding.sampleText.text = stringFromJNI()
        stringFromJNI()
    }

   
    external fun stringFromJNI(): Int

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("cpp_trial")
        }
    }
}
```

I knonw it is probably a stupid question ,but I am very new to android development , and find no result after search on the web.And thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is your actual question or error message? Are you aware that Qt has native support for Android and allows you to write Qt applications without necessarily needing JNI?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is odd. AndroidStudio is the compiler for Android development. You introduced qt without cross-compiling. Executing c++ for Android, or qt for example, requires ndk cross-compilation.

We have not compiled qt with cross-compile. I don't think this is advisable. qt is an engine similar to a platform.